# How to force a minimal gcc version with autotools?

Tags: gcc, c++11, version, autotools

I have forked a project that use autotools, and added functionalities that require c++11, then at least gcc 4.7.

What shall I add in configure.ac to check if gcc version 4.7 at least is available ? and then to use the minimal version that fits this requirement, or the system default version if it is higher ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other compilers beside GCC that support C++11, why make a test for a specific version of GCC?

The Autoconf Archive has [a macro to require C++11 support](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html#ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11), from whatever compiler is being used.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a GCC installation also includes an executable with the same name but with a version included in the name. So if you have GCC version 4.7 then besides having a `g++` program you also have a `g++-4.7`.

When you know that, you can use something like this:

```
dnl # Check which GCC version is wanted
AC_ARG_WITH(gcc,
  [ --with-gcc=<version> Use GCC (gcc and g++) of the specified version],
  [if test "$withval" != yes; then
     AC_PROG_CXX([g++-$withval g++ c++])
     AC_PROG_CC([gcc-$withval gcc])
   elif test "$withval" = yes; then
     AC_PROG_CXX([g++ c++])
     AC_PROG_CC([gcc])
   fi])
```

Modify to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joachim. I read the doc for AC_ARG_WITH, but I don't understand it and I don't know how to "modify to my requirements". Could you please provide it as a complete example, I don't know here what is comment or not.

Comment: @lalebarde Actually, after thinking a little about it, forcing a specific compiler and compiler versions is the wrong way to go. Instead you should check that the compiler can handle the constructs you want it to handle. This means you should have checks for e.g. `nullptr` if you use that. See e.g. [this `configure.ac` of mine](https://github.com/pileon/shadow-server/blob/pre-cmake/configure.ac) for examples of that. It check for the `-std=c++11` (and `-std=c++0x`) flags, and other misc. C++11 features (like `nullptr`, Unicode string literals and raw string literals).